# Draw This ASCII art In The Least Amount Of Bytes(edited)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

your challenge is to draw this ASCII art:

```
|     |  |- - - -  |       |       - - -   
|     |  |         |       |       |   |  
|- - -|  |- - -    |       |       |   | 
|     |  |         |       |       |   | 
|     |  |- - - -  |- - -  |- - -  - - -
```

remember this is `code golf` meaning you have to answer in the least amount of bytes possible.
EDIT: spacing between letters is two spaces. the only symbols used are | and -. NO underscores. i added spaces between the dashes to make it easier to see how many there are

Comment: Can you add a description of how to draw it (dimensions, spacing, characters, etc.)? The title is also very vague, and applies to any [tag:ascii-art] challenge. I'd recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges.

Comment: is there a mistake at the bottom of the `E` or is this on purpose to have a `-` instead of a `—`? (just for the sake of nitpicking, it actually introduces a welcomed conmplexity IMO)

Comment: @Kaddath personally, I'd prefer it without the odd character on the E. At a certain point, odd quirks lead to uninteresting off-the-shelf compression based algorithms. I'd also prefer the use of ASCII `-` throughout. Use of non-ASCII characters excludes certain languages.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt totally valid points, I tend to forget ASCII only languages (and the question is called ASCII art after all)

Comment: Justin, to add to @RedwolfPrograms points, I'd note that you should specify what whitespace is permitted: additional space to the right (trailing spaces)? to the left? above? below (trailing newlines)? Your example output is non-rectangular and has different amounts of frailing whitespace on different lines.

Comment: Justin, this is why you're attracting close votes, and why you should post in the sandbox first. Since your edit, this is a completely different question (a better question, but a completely different one.) You already have one answer from @Kaddath which is now invalid. You also haven't addressed my point about what whitespace is allowed. I predict this question will get closed and probably not reopened, which is sad because it could have been avoided. Please try answering a few challenges to get used to the site, and post your next one in the sandbox first for feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 52 bytes

```
•C"¹Ò∞ʒÓŸ2ýŸ¦ÙLŒðd4Í}‡éλPÓãžãš±àýEŽª™§M₆2•… |-ÅвJ5ä»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWkAlv9vc2FiaWX//@KAokMiwrnDkuKInsqSw5PFuDLDvcW4wqbDmUzFksOwZDTDjX3igKHDqc67UMOTw6PFvsOjxaHCscOgw71Fxb3CquKEosKnTeKChjLigKLigKYgfC3DhdCySjXDpMK7//8)

```
•...•… |-ÅвJ5ä»  # full program
              »  # join...
           J     # joined...
         Åв      # characters in...
     … |-        # literal...
         Åв      # with indices in digits of...
•...•            # 88667318995411980279046696478254356886483104218636819581201379955454517801745112819324119476267...
         Åв      # in base length of...
     … |-        # literal...
             ä   # split into...
            5    # literal...
             ä   # equal sized pieces...
              »  # by newlines
                 # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
<?=gzinflate('«Q  ÒU€@&`a^®¸J4Èt
P%XÂL<*‰7‹;Ñh0');
```

**WARNING**: this code contains many non-printable chars and a function that is disabled in most online code testers. It is either impossible to enter the correct code on their sites or run the function. Here is the php file I uploaded to gitHub so that you can test (I recommend using `<pre><code>` tags to see it as intended in a browser, because of spaces being narrower than `—`, and new lines ignored in HTML):

[Try it OFFline!](https://github.com/Kaddath-R/Shared-Files/blob/main/SE-Golf/220031-ascii-hello.php)

Well this is a one-time trick that is becoming recurrent, and quite boring, as all I need to do is reuse the script I made to generate the file, replace the string and run it. So this is the last time I'll use this trick, and I post it as a demonstration of why these challenges are not that much interesting IMO.

EDIT: updated the answer and the file with edited question (the string is shorter, so from 94 bytes originally to 63)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 54 bytes

```
≔…- ⁵θ↓³↗→θ↑³Ｍχ¹←…- ⁷↓³↗→θＭ²⁰→Ｐ↑²Ｍ⁴→↑²←θ‖Ｏ↓Ｆ²«←←←θＰ↑⁵←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY7dCoIwGIaP9SqGRxsopCWBHYUdJongBciYOhhuzWVEdO1rJuLfWYff@z3vD64LiXnBtD63La0aGL8wI3HNBXQ84LggRC64o5OdStooGF34s3HB3ggJ7wiMcpHRqlYT8DsXllzMDP7OBf70u5LSwOvOI/qv8EcEpiEameTBFBXTjmCkDjMoXf4X0/rYjJSMYHXriGSFGCYZueQSwACBt20N03qH0VfXJs5ajwo3po/W2uvYFw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔…- ⁵θ
```

Construct the string `- - -` as it gets used a lot.

```
↓³↗→θ↑³
```

Draw the top half of the `H`.

```
Ｍχ¹←…- ⁷↓³↗→θ
```

Draw the top half of the `E`.

```
Ｍ²⁰→Ｐ↑²Ｍ⁴→↑²←θ
```

Draw the top half of the `O`.

```
‖Ｏ↓
```

Reflect to complete the `HE  O`.

```
Ｆ²«←←←θＰ↑⁵←
```

Draw two `L`s.

Or I could just do boring string compression for 51 bytes:

```
”~∨CθＯÀ·y←B～⊟⧴n^；δＳ3E⊖⎇✂↶0¶KZ7≦%⊕wG4Ｈ⁻φ｜eＰυυ[qπ<Φ⊙›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREOpRgEEgGSNrgIEKkCEEDRYOCYPoVJBAU0FMl0DVAnWgTATj0rizcTiTjQaTClpWv///1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code.

If there were no spaces in the horizontal lines, it would be only 44 bytes:

```
↓³↗→⁵↑³Ｍχ¹←⁷↓³↗→⁵Ｍ²⁴→↑²←⁴Ｐ↓³←¹‖Ｏ↓Ｆ²«←←←⁵Ｐ↑⁵←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88T0fBWNOayze/LFXDKrQgKDM9owTIhyoAc3UUTBEioQVIGgwNdBQMEXI@qWlAxeYIAVLMB6swMtFRsEJTA7LRCN0SE5CO0pySzAJ0m1CUgRwXlJqWk5pc4l@WWpSTWABRChROyy9S0DDSVKjm4oQ4DqQDKI7GQzHOFCyPZC3IbaYYmmr///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code.